# Find value in one column and return value of a specified cell in the row found in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have something like this:

[image]

Where I'd like to return in `E3`, the value of `B` of the row that matches with `D3`.

`=IF(A:A="D3",return the value from B from the row that matches with D3)`

Comment: Hopefully I have "improved" your title *(since you were unhappy with it)*. If you disagree, please change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this formula

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,A2:B,2,0)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)